# I can't acces a PC file on a LAN, but in my local files I can

Tags: java

The code works perfectly in local files, but when I try to access a network device, I get a connection error to the address of the specified network machine, which I could do to solve it.

I attach the code here:

Main.java

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static String machinename;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Jframe components are defined here
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("La tikets");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(650 , 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // el panel no está visible en la salida
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(); // el panel no está visible en la
        JLabel Label1 =  new JLabel("Introducir nombre de la maquina");
        JLabel WordCountLabel = new JLabel("Cantidad");
        JButton Buscar = new JButton("Buscar");
        JButton restablecer = new JButton("Restablecer");
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(15);
    
        // Componentes are added to the panels here
        panel.add(Label1);
        panel.add(tf);
        panel.add(Buscar);
        panel.add(restablecer);
        panel2.add(WordCountLabel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.PAGE_END, panel2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    
        //action button listener  for run the (DevolverValor) function
        Buscar.addActionListener(e -> {
            try {
                machinename = tf.getText();
                DevolverValor.Leer(machinename);
                WordCountLabel.setText("Tikets impresos: "+DevolverValor.Leer(Arrays.toString(args)));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });
    
        restablecer.addActionListener(e -> tf.setText(""));
    }
}
```

DevolverValor.java

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DevolverValor {
    public static int Leer(String machinename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String WordToSearch = "Data:";
        int wordCount = 0;
    
        File text = new File("\\\\"+machinename+"\\C$\\SITA\\Logs\\BlaServer\\BSIA.log.1");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(text);
    
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            if (s.next().equals(WordToSearch)) {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
    
        System.out.println(machinename);
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```

I have tried to search forums and videos, and I have not been able to fix it, in local files of my PC if it works, or I understand what happens.

Returns the folowing error :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C68h.png)

Comment: Does your user have admin access to said computer? Because that is what `C$` does. Its an admin access

Comment: does that path work when you open it in the windows explorer? Also all the shares containing the drive letter and the `$` should not be used by applications, as @XtremeBaumer pointed out.

Comment: Please provide the exception stacktrace of the error you receive.

Comment: Yes the user is the admin of the network, and  the path works when i open in windows explorer

Comment: have you tried accessing a local file via a unc path (to rule out connection issues)  like `"\\\\localhost\\C$\\temp\\BSIA.log.1"` - this would help troublehott if the issue is the `C$` share